# Need help in iterating a list from a list object in Spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, iterator

I have searched several examples, still have not get. I am passing an List of GOOD object from controller into jsp pages. In this object i have UserName and list of FUNCTIONS which is another an object. I want to iterate through the GOOD list and want to display name and corresponding functions but not able to do so. 
My GOOD bean is:

```
public List<Function> userFunctionsList = new ArrayList<Function>();
public String userName;
```

My ACCESS Bean is:

```
public List<Good> goodBeanList = new ArrayList<Good>();
public List<Good> getGoodBeanList() {
        return goodBeanList;
    }
    public void setGoodBeanList(
            List<Good> goodBeanList) {
        this.goodBeanList = goodBeanList;
    }
```

My Controller class:

```
    public ModelAndView getUserDetails(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response)
        {
        List<Good> searchedUsersList = null;
        List<Good> finalList = new ArrayList<ManageCorporateServices>();
        Access accessBean = new Access();
        searchedUsersList = goodService.getSearchedUsers(contractId,userName);

        for(Good goodBean : searchedUsersList)
        {
          userFunctionsList = goodService.getUserFunctions(goodBean.getUserName());
          goodBean.setUserFunctionsList(userFunctionsList);
          finalList.add(goodBean);
        }
    access.setGoodBeanList("finalList");
    modelAndView.adObject("access",access);
```

In JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="access" action="${updateFunctionNew}">
    <c:forEach var="userNamesListValue" items="${access.goodBeanList }">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="${selectedUserName}" title="selectedUserName">${userNamesListValue.userName}</a>
            </td>
            <c:forEach  varStatus = "count" var="userFunctionsList" items="${userNamesListValue.userFunctionsList}">
            <td>${userFunctionsList.functionName} <form:checkbox  path="userFunctionsList[${count.index }].updatedValue" value="${userFunctionsList.updatedValue}" /></td>
            </c:forEach>
            <td><button type="Submit" class="pink">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

I am getting userFunctionsList[0] not readable property in Access Bean error. Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following

```
<form:checkbox  path="userFunctionsList[${count.index }].updatedValue"
```

Is appended to your command object, which in your case is an *Access* object. That's why you're getting an error, its search the userFunctionsList against an *Access*  bean not the *Good* bean

To fix it, add an index to your outer loop as well, and correct your path, something like

```
<c:forEach var="userNamesListValue" items="${access.goodBeanList }" varStatus="accessCount"
  ....
  <form:checkbox  path="goodBeanList[${accessCount.index}].userFunctionsList[${count.index }].updatedValue"
```

Comment: Now it is throwing Invalid property 'userNamesListValue[0]' of bean class [com.Access]: Bean property 'userNamesListValue[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: make sure that you have getters and setters for your bean, see my edit

Comment: I have getters / setters in the beans. I did not mentioned those in this post for readibility.

Comment: its my bad, see the edited resonse, I was not accessing a goodBeanList property, fixed now